# Get the column names of malformed records while reading a csv file using pyspark

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am reading a csv file using pyspark with predefined schema.

```
schema = StructType([
StructField("col1", IntegerType(), True),
StructField("col2", StringType(), True)
StructField("col3", FloatType(), True)
])

df = spark.sqlContext.read
    .schema(schema)
    .option("header",true)
    .option("delimiter", ",")
    .csv(path)
```

Now in the csv file, there is float value in col1 and string value in col3. I need to raise an exception and get the names of these columns(col1, col3) because these columns contain the values of different data type than that of defined in schema.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

In pyspark versions >2.2 you can use `columnNameOfCorruptRecord` with [csv](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.streaming.DataStreamReader.csv):

```
schema = StructType(
    [
        StructField("col1", IntegerType(), True),
        StructField("col2", StringType(), True),
        StructField("col3", FloatType(), True),
        StructField("corrupted", StringType(), True),
    ]
)

df = spark.sqlContext.read.csv(
    path,
    schema=schema,
    header=True,
    sep=",",
    mode="PERMISSIVE",
    columnNameOfCorruptRecord="corrupted",
).show()

+----+----+----+------------+
|col1|col2|col3|   corrupted|
+----+----+----+------------+
|null|null|null|0.10,123,abc|
+----+----+----+------------+
```

**EDIT:** CSV record fields are not independent of one another, so it can't generally be said that one field is corrupt, but others are not. Only the entire record can be corrupt or not corrupt.

For example, suppose we have a comma delimited file with one row and two floating point columns, the Euro values `0,10` and `1,00`. The file looks like this:

```
col1,col2
0,10,1,00
```

Which field is corrupt?

Comment: This gives entire row of malformed value. I need column names like col1 and col3. How do I get those column names ?

Comment: Good question. See my answer above.

Comment: Thanks Dave. That's true in case of European numbering system. In python we can specify a parameter decimal= ',' . But in pyspark I guess there is no option like this. Only way is read data as string and then use regex. But in my case, I need to know column names. Is there way to get it?